# How to mock the readonly 'ushort' type property of an interface in nSubstitute?

Tags: unit-testing, nsubstitute

I need to mock an Interface which has readonly 'ushort' type properties. Looks like nSubstitute doesn't let me set those properties.
public interface IExampleInterface
{
ushort ID{ get; }
......
}

```
IExampleInterface mockObject = Substitute.For<IExampleInterface>();
mockObject.ID.Returns(0x12);  /// not allowed. error:
                              /// ushort does not contain a definition for 'Returns' 
                              /// and the best extension method overload 
                              /// 'SubstituteExtensions.Returns<int>(int, int, params int[])'
                              /// requires a receiver of type 'int'
mockObject.ID = 0x12;    /// not allowed
```

If I change the line to the following, it seems to work.

```
(int)mockObject.ID).Returns(0x12);
```

Is this the right way to workaround the original error?

Comment: _readonly properties_ - Do you mean `string Name { get; }`? Then `mockObject.Name.Returns("ABC");` works.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I edited the original post, the issue was around 'ushort' type property. I thought it was the same for all types and used string type as an example.

Comment: `mockObject.Id.Returns<ushort>(0x12);`

Answer (score 0):

The `0x12` literal is considered the `int` type by default.

From here, the return type of the `Returns(0x12)` expression is also `int`.

Therefore, you must explicitly specify the desired type.

```
mockObject.Id.Returns<ushort>(0x12);
```